# How can computational requirements be compared?

Tags: requirements

Calculating the solution to an optimization problem takes a 2 GHz CPU one hour. During this process there are no background processes, no RAM is being used and the CPU is at 100% capacity.

Based on this information, can it be derived that a 1 GHz CPU will take two hours to solve the same problem?

Comment: There may be vast architectural differences in any two CPUs; the GHz number alone says little about its performance in any particular calculation…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search of IPC, frequence, and chip architecture will show you this topic has been breached many times. There are many things that can determine the execution speed of a program (without even going into threading at all) the main ones that pop to mind:

1. **Instruction set** - If one chip has an instruction for multiplication, than `a*b` is atomic. If not, you will need a lot of atomic instructions to perform such an action - big difference in speed, which can prove to make even higher frequency chips slower.
2. Cycles per second - this is the **frequency** of the chip.
3. **Instructions per cycle (IPC)** - what you are really interested is IPC*frequency, not just frequency. How many atomic actions can you can perform in a second. After the amount of atomic actions (see 1), on a single threaded application this might act as you expect (x2 this => x2 faster program), though no guarantees.

and there are a ton of other nuance technologies that can affect this, like branch prediction which hit the news big time recently. For a complete understanding a book/course might be a better resource.

So, in general, **no**. If you are comparing two single core, same architecture chips (unlikely), then maybe yes.

Comment: I see. Wondering about the magnitude of these factors compared to the frequency by itself... Could the frequency be used as a rule of thumb when estimating the computational time of an Arduino if the comp. time on, say a modern ThinkPad, is known - or could I expect huge deviations of >100%?

Comment: @cheesus expect deviations. It matters of course how complex is your program for the test, but frequency by itself is usually a bad indicator except for nearly identical (architecture wise) chips.

Comment: The instruction set by itself can make a giant difference.